# failed to load resources show status code 400() in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch-api, .env

trying to post data using fetch api and it shows failed load resources show status code 400()
what kind of error is this

````
function register() {
    let item = { email };
    console.log(item);

    const order = {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json, charset=utf-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: email }),
    };

    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}v1/auth/email-signup`, order)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response", response);
        navigate("/otp");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("e", e);
      });

    
  }```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you receive a 400 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors), it means that the sever received your request but the content was not valid. Read the documentation of the API to be sure you send the correct payload.

```
function register() {
    let item = { email };
    console.log(item);

    const order = {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json, charset=utf-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: email }),
    };

    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}v1/auth/email-signup`, order)
      .then(res => res.json()) // new line
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("data", data);
        navigate("/otp");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("e", e);
      });
```